# what replaces Hibernate.entity() in Hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

I have an  an application in which i want to migrate the jar from hibernate 3.6 to hibernate 5. it is throwing error.

```
The method entity(Class<Realty>) is undefined for the type Hibernate
```

The code that is i am writing is:--

```
query.setParameter("objectTableInformation", contractObject.getTableMetaInformation(), Hibernate
     .entity(SysTableInformation.class));
```

Please suggest  me what i need to give in place of :-

```
Hibernate.entity(SysTableInformation.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following :-

```
session.getTypeHelper().entity(SysTableInformation.class);
//where session is your session object
```